# Problema com NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho uma classe IMObject, nela tenho um campo NSDate *StartDate.
Preencho este campo com um retorno do banco de dados:

```
 (IMMutableArrayIMTable*)[databaseTemp retrieve: @"select * from table" withParams:nil forClass: [IMTable class]]
```

No Watch do XCode vejo o valor do objeto como:

```
StartDate = (_NSDate *) 2014-05-28 08:00:00:00 BRT
```

Porém, se eu der um print neste campo ele me mostra 3 horas a mais, no caso **2014-05-28 11:00:00:00**.

Creio que possa ser algum problema de fuso horário, mas não sei como resolver.
O meu projeto está com o Localizations Portuguese.
Alguém sabe como resolver ou tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está claro como você manipula o banco, e em particular, o campo de data. Seria necessário ver o código de escrita e leitura e saber qual a tecnologia usada.
De qualquer forma, para formatar um objeto do tipo `NSDate` utiliza-se um objeto `NSDateFormatter`, exemplo:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd EEEE"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

No exemplo foi utilizado um `NSDateFormatter` para formatar a representação textual do objeto `date`, forçando o locale pra pt_BR (do contrário seria usado o locale do dispositivo).

Creio que no seu caso é preciso criar um formatter para salvar e ler as datas no banco como string, uma vez que sqlite não possui um tipo específico para datas, e quantos mais precisar para manipular as datas para visualização.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser imprimir um objeto do tipo `NSDate`, você deve usar um `NSDateFormatter`. No formatter você pode definir o fuso horário (*time zone*) que deve ser usada para converter a data para um string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:StartDate];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", dateString);
```